# É possível burlar (bypass) uma expressão regular?

Tags: php, regex

Estou lendo um pouco sobre regex para algumas validações e queria saber se existe alguma forma de burlar alguma regra, por exemplo:

```
$rule = "/[^A-Za-z0-9]/";
```

Encontrei esta para validar campos alfanuméricos, existe alguma forma de burlar isso e escapar outros caracteres?

Comment: Talvez possa ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323977/how-to-bypass-reqular-expression-validation-for-specific-characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No exemplo acima a variável `$rule` está recebendo um padrão que casa com qualquer coisa não alfanumérica.

Para validar alfanuméricos, este padrão provavelmente será utilizado para substituir tudo que casar com o mesmo por uma String de comprimento zero ("").

Se você quer saber se no exemplo citado é possível que algum caracter não alfanumérico permaneça na String após a substituição a resposta é **NÃO**.

```
$string = 'qualquer coisa !@#$%¨&())_+';
$rule = "/[^A-Za-z0-9]/";
$resultado = preg_replace($rule, "", $string);
echo $resultado;
```

Resultado:

> qualquercoisa

Perceba que nem o espaço passou.

Só é possível burlar uma expressão regular se houver falhas na elaboração da mesma. Caso contrário, como no exemplo citado, **não dá**.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado!